# How to get a hidden information (average review) from an Amazon products page?(web scraping)

Tags: python, web-scraping

How can I get the average star rating(example 4.3 out of 5 stars) from this amazon template (https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_1?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A1055398%2Cn%3A1063306%2Ck%3Aas&keywords=as&ie=UTF8&qid=1532070774) for every product of this page. This is an amazon products page. The problem is on the second try/catch block with review. I attached the code. I will appreciate any help. Thank you.

```
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from lxml import html
import io

links = [
    'https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_1?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A1055398%2Cn%3A1063306%2Ck%3Aas&keywords=as&ie=UTF8&qid=1532070774'
 ]
proxies = {
    'http': 'http://218.50.2.102:8080',
    'https': 'http://185.93.3.123:8080'
}

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server="%s"' % ';'.join(['%s=%s' % (k, v) for k, v in proxies.items()]))

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\Andrei-PC\Downloads\webdriver\chromedriver.exe",
                              chrome_options=chrome_options)
header = ['Product title', 'Product price', 'Review', 'ASIN']

with open('csv/demo.csv', "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    writer.writerow(header)
for i in range(len(links)):

    driver.get(links[i])
    for x in range(0,23):
        product_title = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//li[@id="result_{}"]/div/div[3]/div/a'.format(x))
        title = [x.text for x in product_title]

        try:
            price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@id="result_{}"]/div/div[5]/div/a/span[2]'.format(x)).text
        except:
            price = 'No price v2'
            print('No price v2')

        try:
            review = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@id="result_{}"]/div/div[6]/span'.format(x)).text()

        except:
            review = 'No review v1'
            print('No review v1')

        try:
            asin = driver.find_element_by_id('result_{}'.format(x)).get_attribute('data-asin')

        except:
            asin = 'No asin'
            print('No asin')

        try:
            data = [title[0], price, review, asin]
        except:
            print('no items v3 ')
        with io.open('csv/demo.csv', "a", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as output:
            writer = csv.writer(output)
            writer.writerow(data)
    print('I solved this link %s' % (links[i]))
    print('Number of product %s' % (i + 1))
```

Comment: You say there is "a problem" but not what it is. What is it? (Do not answer in comments. You can always [edit] your own question and add missing details.)

Comment: The problem is on the second  try/except block with review. It didn't print the review correctly but I solved. Thank you for interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rate with below code:

```
stars = driver.find_element_by_class_name('a-icon-alt').get_attribute('textContent')
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives me a blank space. I think this is a dynamic information using javascript(they make an average).

Comment: Should I set an option from the browser to disable javascript or to change the browser? Now I'm using chrome.

Comment: Check updated. It's not dynamic data, but the text is hidden, so just use `get_attribute('textContent')` instead of `text`

Comment: Now it gives me Prime for all the products

Comment: Prime? What do you mean? If you're working with the list of elements, try `driver.find_elements_by_class_name('a-icon-alt')[x].get_attribute('textContent')` where `x` is  the index of element

Comment: Yes that is. Thank you again. You help me a lot and you save me a lot of time.

Comment: It appears a problem. There are 2 elements with the class a-icon-alt(the span tag with the text Prime and the review). I tried to use driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('span.a-icon-alt:last-child').get_attribute('textContent') but it doesnt work, and I also try with xpath. So i think I have to select the last span element with the class a-icon-alt. Look at the second product of this page ('Cube Chairs Set......'). Can you please help me with this problem?

Comment: `i.a-icon-star>span.a-icon-alt`

Comment: Yes. It returns the review. But for the last 4 items in csv I don't know why it returns No review v1. For these products(Product one -""""Chests of Drawers, LITTLE TREE Tall Accent Chest with Open Storage"""""""", Product two """"""""Modern Innovations Bedside Tray with Cup Holder""""""""""""" , Product three """"""""""Mantua Cottage Style Wedgewood Blue""""""""""' and Product four """""""""""""""Step Stool Folding Aluminum RV Step Platform""""""""""""""')

Comment: I don't see that HTML somehow differs from other products. That might be problem with the loop itself... You'd better post new ticket regarding this issue as I see no reason to not return correct output

Comment: I will post a new question on stackoverflow now regarding this problem.

Comment: The question is "Why my program returns “No review v1” instead of returning the average review for the products with reviews?(web scraping, python)". Can you please take a look?Thanks!